# There is a number $x$ such that $n\lt x\lt n+1$? and where can I find more exercises like this one?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that given $n\in \mathbb N$, there isn't a natural number such that $n\lt x\lt n+1$, using the axioms of the natural numbers and the definition of $\lt$ ($m\lt n$ iff $n=m+p$, $p\in \mathbb N$). I've already proved associativity, commutativity and cancellation law of the natural numbers. So we can use this to prove this question, I need help here.

By the way, anyone knows where can I find more exercises like this one in order to train the axioms and first definitions of numbers?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have additive inverses?

Comment: http://www.ithaca.edu/seltzer/analysis/archimedean.pdf

Comment: @Clayton That's cancellation. Inquest, That's not what the OP is asking, though I admit I thought it was at first as well.

Comment: @proximal: Thanks; I wasn't sure whether to consider multiplication or not.

Comment: @Clayton that's my problem, I don't have additive inverses, if I had, it would be easy.

Comment: @Inquest I can't use the archimedean property, we are working on the natural numbers.

Comment: @user42912: Do you have anything like $1+1<1+2\Longrightarrow 1<2$? In particular, $n+m<n+p$ implies $m<p$?

Comment: @Clayton I only have if $m\lt n$, then $m+p\lt n+p$ for natural numbers $p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to reflect new information.

Since $x > n$, if we assume $x \in \mathbb{N}$ then we can write $x = n + a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $n < n + a < n + 1$.

Proceed by cases on $a$ to reach a contradiction for any $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What I did so far: since $n\lt x\lt n+1$, then there are natural numbers $a, b$ such that $n+1=x+a$ and $x=n+b$, am I in the right way?

Comment: thank you a lot, now I got the contradiction! :)

Answer (score 2):

The key is to prove that there are no natural numbers between $0$ and $1$. You will then also need the following lemmas:

Lemma 1: If $a < b$ and $c \leq a$, $a-c < b-c$.

Lemma 2: If $a < b$ then $a^2 < b^2$.

Lemma 3: If $a < b$ and $c>0$, then $ac < bc.$

Let $S= \{a\in \mathbb{N} \vert 0 < a < 1\}$ and assume, for contradiction, that $S$ is nonempty. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered, $S$ has a least element $b$. By Lemma 2,
$$0 < b^2 < 1,$$
so $b^2 \in S$. Moreover, by Lemma 3, $b^2 < b$, a contradiction, since $b$ is the least element of $S$. Therefore $S$ is empty and there are no natural numbers between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try by contradiction and use cancellation.

Comment: I'm trying this, but I don't know how to use the cancellation in this case, since $n\lt x\lt n+1$, then there are natural numbers $a, b$ such that $n+1=x+a$ and $x=n+b$, am I in the right way?